# how C programming allows the hardware level control?

Tags: c

I read somewhere that learning c programming gives us the actual idea of what is happening in the hardware level i.e. C programming teach us the real programming like how the memory is being utilised, how the hardware resources are used and it allows us to interfere with hardware level stuff like we are the one who can use and can control these resources in our own way as we want but other high level languages don't allow this.
Now I am learning C programming but I am not able to understand that how I am controlling my hardware resource ?
I have no idea how it is allowing us to use my computer resources independently.

Comment: Most C you will ever see is completely hardware and platform agnostic. If you want to look at C code that interacts with hardware, download the Linux kernel and look at some drivers.

Comment: @Cheatah: Very little C code is completely hardware and platform agnostic. Programs that do abstract mathematics, implement text adventures, or do simple file processing can be platform agnostic, but little else can be. Anything that puts up a GUI window must call platform library routines. Anything with network interactions uses platform features. Many C programs rely on some aspects of types beyond the C standard minimum requirements. There is an illusion on Stack Overflow that fully portable C code is common, but that is because Stack Overflow often works with tiny snippets of code.

Comment: Many programming languages are able to access hardware directly, even if C has a reputation for this. To control your hardware resources, the first step is to learn about those resources. Which resources are you thinking about? What do you mean by "_to use [...] **independently**_"? Independent of what? "_I read somewhere_" is not helpful, please be more specific, especially on "_other high level languages don't allow this_". Which languages?

Comment: I recommend reading a book or taking a course on microcontrollers, you will find most of the answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In user mode, using a 32 or 64 bits multitask operating system, even C won't show you a tiny bit of hardware - lowest level you'll see is operating system itself.

You may ask the OS to draw a window, to save a file, to send data through a network - you won't touch directly GPU, disk controller or Ethernet MAC/Phy chip to be able to do that. In fact, you probably won't even be able to tell which **KIND** of hardware is behind... Is it a Nvidia card? An old SVGA one? A mechanical hard drive, or a NVMe drive? A 10BaseT NIC, or a 10 Gb/s optical fiber network card? You can't tell just with C. Only OS knows it, and it's OS that may tell it. You'll get that in C exactly like you would have got it with, let's say, Python.

---

To see hardware and how it works, you'll need to be able to ***touch*** hardware with software instructions. On a modern OS, it means being in kernel mode. Or to use an old-timer OS, like MS-DOS, or even no OS at all - called "bare metal development", often encountered with microcontrollers like Arduino and similar devices.

In this world, you'll need to learn what a register is, how GPIO works, how you address an UART, and if you use specific controllers, you'll have to read (and understand!) their datasheets if you want to make them work.

Indeed, it's often easier to do such low-level code in C, rather than in Assembler - especially since each CPU has its own assembler, so that may become a lot of languages to master *in fine*. But it's not mandatory. It can also be done with any language, as long as you can produce an absolute (=relocated), standalone (=no dependencies) and ROMable binary that can be written in Flash/EEPROM for your microcontroller. It can be done in assembler, C, C++, ADA for the most common ones, and virtualy any language that don't need a (too) big runtime library.